# Drag and drop list - not working with my data structure (stackblitz included)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-dragdrop

I decided to make smaller implementation from my big project. At this moment i trying to rework list for drag&drop functionality. In my project i see names on list but can't drag and drop anything. In stackblitz i can't even show anything on my list. I [using](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) this to make drag&drop. [There](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybu1xz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html) is my stackblitz with smaller implementation.

## Edit 1

It will be nice when drag&drop will be combined with material list.

## Edit 2

When i remove observable from file element, error disappears, but sadly still not working. Observable is required there.

Answer (score 0):

TS File

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
;
import { transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
/**
 * @title Drag&Drop sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: "cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example",
  templateUrl: "cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.css"]
})
export class CdkDragDropSortingExample {
  todo = [
    {
      name: "Pictures",
      extension: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Movies",
      extension: ""
    }
  ];
  done = [
    {
      name: "Pictures2",
      extension: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Movies2",
      extension: ""
    }
  ];


  ngOnInit() {}
   drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML FILE

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>To do</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[check Stackblizfor answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybu1xz-axkyk5?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: Your answer totally missing file service and observables. This is really required in my project, i can't avoid that. I made other changes from your example and still can't see single row.